# Should I start a py file with coding information?

Tags: python, utf-8, formatting, pep8

Can you tell me how I should formalize my `.py` file.

From some sources I've found that all files should start with:

```
# coding : utf-8
# PEP-8
```

Some people on GitHub do this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

However, Google for example doesn't use either of these and start files with license information:

```
# Copyright (C) 2018 Google Inc.
# Licensed under http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 <see LICENSE file>
```

What is the best and accepted way?

Comment: IIRC, the `# PEP-8` declaration is an "opt-in" used by one of the super-checker tools that run a slew of format checkers, linters, etc., on your code, to specify that this file should be run through the `pep8` checker and rejected if there are any warnings. If I'm remembering right, it's probably obsolete, as (a) `pep8` is deprecated in favor of `pycodestyle`, and (b) neither of the current up-to-date super-checkers seems to use this declaration so it's probably one of the two that are no longer maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

Python 2 used ASCII as default encoding for source files.

Python 3's default is UTF-8.

So, if you intend to only support Python 3+ then you don't have to declare the utf-8 encoding as it is already the default.

If you intend to support Python 2 as well and you have non-ASCII string literals then you should declare an encoding.

If your text editor also needs a coding declaration (e.g., if your Unix locale is set to, say, Latin-1, but your code is UTF-8), Python's lenient syntax allows a single declaration to be used for both—e.g., `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is recognized by both emacs and Python.

Some official information:

Python 3's docs about unicode support: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support

PEP 263 that introduced the encoding declaration syntax: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

PEP 3210 about changing the default encoding from ASCII to UTF-8 starting from Python 3.0: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/

Comment: It might also be worth adding links to [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and [PEP 3120](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/), and maybe explaining the difference between the different coding declaration styles (basically, sharing the coding declaration between Python and emacs and/or vi).

Comment: Thanks, cool. How about PEP-8 line and licence?

Comment: @abarnert, thanks, added some references

Comment: @MAxShvedov I doubt you will find any PEP about that. It is up to personal preferences and organizational conventions.

Comment: @DeepSpace I got it, thank you again.

Comment: Minor change: UTF-8 is the encoding; Unicode is what's encoded. Also, added a paragraph that explains the funky syntax the OP is seeing (many people on GitHub use emacs, vi, or both, so they use a coding declaration that's shared with their editor).

Comment: @abarnert Fair enough, thanks for the edit

Comment: @MAxShvedov If you're publishing code under some license, you should read the license to see what it requires. But most of them don't require a comment per file, just one per repo (and if you let GitHub auto-generate a repo for you with a specific license, it will take care of that automatically).